# Delphi Firemonkey iOS App AppStore Upload with ssl static libraries

Tags: ios, delphi, openssl, app-store, indy

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

yesterday I tried to upload my App to the Apple AppStore.
I used the uploader and got an Error telling me I'm not allowed to upload a bundle containing the libraries libssl.a and libcryptossl.a. My App is using Indy Components and SSL libraries to secure the communication between Server and mobile App.
I was able to directly deploy my app to my phone and communicate with my server. Now I want to take the next step and beta test my via testflight.

My question is, Apple rejects to upload the libraries, how am I able to secure the communication between my server and my mobile app with SSL?

I'm using Delphi Rio 10.3.2 with Firemonkey framework.
My Server is using a self signed SSL certificate, so does my mobile App.

best regards

Comment: You can use Delphi RTL provided HTTP Client that uses OS provided security API-s. [Using an HTTP Client](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_an_HTTP_Client)

Comment: this RTL http Client is able to use my self signed Client Certificate? I tried at the start of my project and I was not able to make an ssl secured call to my server. That's the reason I switched to indy.

Comment: I don't know. There were some issues around certificates and they might be resolved in the meantime. If you are on subscription, you can also get access to 10.3.3 beta and you can test (use) that one. Also if there are still problems, now would be the best time to report them as after the release you would have to wait for next update (which will most likely be next version 10.4, next year) to have those issues fixed.

Comment: Worth a try... How do I retrieve 10.3.3? I'm on subscription for Delphi Professional + Mobile Packs.

Comment: You should contact your sales representative as mentioned in [Addressing iOS 13 and Android 64-bit with RAD Studio](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/addressing-ios-13-and-android-64-bit-with-rad-studio) probably also through Installation and registration support https://www.embarcadero.com/support

Comment: If you can find particular bug reports for those issues and post their number(s) here, I can relay that information to the dev team.

Comment: @LarsP regarding the use of OpenSSL on iOS, you are not supposed to deploy the OpenSSL libs at all. Indy uses OpenSSL *statically* on iOS, the lib code is compiled directly into your executable. The libs are needed only on your dev machine. Did you follow the instructions at [Using Open SSL in Delphi iOS](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/using_ssl_delphi_ios.html)?

Comment: thank you @RemyLebeau I did not know that. I compiled again and was able to upload and deploy my app. Right now I'm waiting for approvement of the apple review team.